# Appropriate tags for equation formulation question

Tags: discussion, tagging, allowed-questions, specific-question

I'm a biologist-turned-programmer (yes, one of *those*) trying to write up equations describing my code. I'm in the process of writing a question about it (it includes a description of the algorithm and the LaTeX of what I've tried). To be clear, it's not a typesetting question. I just can't figure out how to clearly express the math.

I have two questions:

1. Is this an appropriate question for this site? If not, is there a better StackExchange site for it?
2. I got to the add tags part and I don't see any that quite fit. It's not exactly homework. I guess it's technically algebra? But my question isn't about how to do the math, it's about how to elegantly represent the math.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198878) is the posted question.

Comment: If you are doing some numerical applied math work [scicomp.se] might be a better fit (or one of the other science sites depending on what you do, biology, physics, earthscience, chemisty, quantitative finance etc). Other than that this site seems fine. You might find the tag [tag:notation] useful.

Comment: Another tag which I would consider related is [tag:article-writing].

Comment: @quid Not to be mistaken for [cs.SE] (It did stump me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion of tag is "mathematical-modeling".  You may find that your problem shares a mathematical formulation with problems from quite different disciplines, so I suspect Math.SE is a good place for this kind of query.

Comment: +1. I also used [article-writing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-writing) and [notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) as suggested in question comments.