# Would questions asking how a concept is modellized/formularized be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

From the comments of this meta question, [Would questions about the importance of a theorem in math on-topic?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34311/157643), it seems to be a consensus that `importance` is a subjective concept, and thus will be off-topic.

However, would questions about how to measure the impact/importance be objective and on-topic? In general, would questions asking how a concept is modellized/formularized be on-topic? The fields where the concepts are used are very likely not math.

Comment: Impact/importance will have the following kind of measure: check the literature in that subject and most likely the number of surveys and professional work that's been done on that subject will be an indicator of how important that field is. I'm not sure how on-topic that is, but I would expect an answer like this to come up, were it asked. However, asking how something is formalized (e.g. how is stochastic filtering used in SoC estimation, details of model etc.?) is actually fine : it's heavily applied math, but there are professional mathematicians who will be working in such a field here.

Comment: However, asking how a "concept" is formalized may also be broad if the concept itself is quite broad, but the kind of question that I mentioned in the previous comment is absolutely fine, because there isn't too much diverse literature on it.

Comment: A closely related previous [Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19988/appropriate-tags-for-equation-formulation-question) discusses the tagging of such posts.  Of course having an apropos tag is not a guarantee that the post itself is on-topic, but with suitable context I suspect you can post a good Question about "how a concept is modellized/formularized".